# How to execute remote pysftp commands under a specific shell

Tags: python, bash, pysftp

I use python module pysftp to connect to remote server.  Below you can see python code :

```
import pysftp
import sys
import sqr_common

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="xxxxxx", username="xxxx",
password="xxxxx")



command  = "/usr/bin/bash"
command2="APSHOME=/all/aps/msc_2012; export APSHOME; "

srv.execute(command)
srv.execute(command2)





srv.close()
```

Problem is that command  /usr/bin/bash  is an infinite process , so my script will never be executed. Can anyone help me how to choose shell on remote server for example bash and execute command in bash on remote server?? Is there any pysftp function that allows me chosing shell??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
/usr/bin/bash -c "APSHOME=/all/aps/msc_2012; export APSHOME; "
```

Comment: thank you after that i tried  command1  = '/usr/bin/bash -c "APSHOME=/all/aps/msc_2012; export APSHOME; PATH=$APSHOME/bin:$PATH"'
command2'/usr/bin/bash -c " PATH=$APSHOME/bin:$PATH; "'

Comment: but get error /usr/bin/bash -c " PATH=$APSHOME/bin:$PATH; "
APSHOME: Undefined variable.

Comment: i tried /usr/bin/bash -c "APSHOME=/all/aps/msc_2012; export APSHOME; PATH=$APSHOME/bin:$PATH"
APSHOME: Undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not specific to Python, but more like how to execute commands under specific shell.

- If you need to run only single command you can run using bash -c switch

  ```
  bash -c "echo 123"
  ```
- You can run multiple commands ; separated

  ```
  bash -c "echo 123 ; echo 246"
  ```
- If you need to many commands under a specific shell, remotely create a shell script file (.bash file) an execute it

  ```
  bash myscript.bash
  ```